# Importing data from notepad to python editor

Tags: python

I have created a list in microsoft notepad...i would like to know if it is possible to import that data to edit in my python editor?

i have used this code but im not sure why it is not working.

```
f = open("productlist.txt","r+")
d = f.readlines()
f.seek(0)
for i in d:
    if i != "Servers":
        f.write(i)
f.truncate()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are taking the value of `f.readlines()` into the variable `d`. so, when you are iterating, you are not going through the file, instead, you are going through the first line of the file. Try doing `d = f.readlines`  instead.

Comment: well, i took a guess. from next time try posting what you wanted to do and what is going wrong in the post.

Comment: @Raj if this answer is correct you should mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark under the up and down arrows